# using export default class with HOC

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I define all my reactjs components using the following syntax:

```
export default class MyClass extends ...
```

However I would like to use a Higher Order Component (HOC) with one of my classes.

I know I can do this:

```
class MyClass extends ...

export default MyHoc()(MyClass);
```

but I was wonder if there was a way to use the HOC but keeping the `export default class` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/). This way you could write:

```
@MyHoc()
export default class MyClass extends ...
```